# LINQ - How to get subset of columns after GroupBy

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

This LINQ-to-SQL query works (testing in LINQpad):

```
var q5 = LOGs.Where(r => r.APP_NAME == "Toaster")  
    .GroupBy(pol => pol.CASE_NO)  
    .Select(grp => grp.First())  
    .OrderByDescending(l => l.WHEN);  
q5.Dump();
```

However, that returns all columns for each row.
How can I refine the Select() part to specify certain columns?
I can do it in two steps by adding .ToList() to the query, then querying q5:

```
var q5a = q5.Select(r => new {CASE=r.CASE_NO, WHEN = r.WHEN});  
q5a.Dump();
```

Can I accomplish that in one statement instead of two?
Thanks --

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you filter after where?

```
 var q5 = LOGs.Where(r => r.APP_NAME == "Toaster")
    .Select(r=> new{r.CASE_NO, r.WHEN})  
    .GroupBy(pol => pol.CASE_NO)  
    .Select(grp => grp.First())  
    .OrderByDescending(l => l.WHEN);
```

remembar that `new {CASE=r.CASE_NO, WHEN = r.WHEN}` creates a new anonymous type because of differents property names, `new {r.CASE_NO, r.WHEN}` doesn't !

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately, in LINQPad I get an error on the GroupBy() call:  `Cannot execute text selection: 'AnonymousType#1' does not contain a definition for 'CASE_NO' and no extension method 'CASE_POL_NO' accepting a first argument of type 'AnonymousType#1' could be found`

Comment: give me 5 minutes to test it

Comment: Thanks!  I discovered you can place the column-selecting Select() after the grp.First() Select().  When I had tried that previously, I must have had the wrong syntax, got an error, and assumed I couldn't chain the Select() methods...

Comment: happy to help you, remembar the key is to not create new type with differents name `new{a=c.Test,b=c.Test2}` doesn't work but `new{c.Test,c.Test2}` works!